# How to SET a VARIABLE while running a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to know how to SET a variable in a batch file while it is running

E.g.

Enter variable name: test

Then I can call this variable later on e.g. %test%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET /P TEST=Enter variable name:
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark the answer as such, so that other users can benefit. Thank you.